# How to brace initialize a std::stack in C++?

Tags: c++, stdarray, stdstack

I have a struct, one of whose members is a std::stack using a std::array as its underlying container:

```cpp
struct S {
  int a, b; // dummy members
  std::stack<
    int, 
    std::array<int, 10>
  > st;
};
```

I would like to use brace initialization to initialize all members of an `S` struct, something like:

```cpp
S const obj {
  1, // a
  2, // b
  {1, 2, 3} /* st
         ^
         I want this at the top of the stack */
};
```

Is this kind of initialization possible for std::stack? If yes, what would the syntax be?

Comment: Note that a stack only allows you to inspect the top element. So a constant stack is not likely to be useful. Additionally, using a `std::array` as the backing container will prevent you from ever poping an element off the top, making the stack equally unlikely to be useful.

Comment: You cannot use a std::array as the underlying container of a std::stack because std::array does not support push_back() and pop_back().